# org.apache.camel.NoSuchEndpointException: No endpoint could be found for: kafkaMessageTransformer

Tags: java, apache-camel

I was working on upgrade camel from 3.0 to 3.4, but I am facing issue when I trying to start the app. JDK8 and All current camel related version: 3.4.0, except for those 2 artifact:

```
camel-restlet(3.0.0-M1)
camel-http4(3.0.0-M1)
```

Define Route and Transformer:

```
RouteKafkaMessageTransformer("direct:kafkaMessageTransformer", false),
StepKafkaMessageTransformer("kafkaMessageTransformer", true),
```

```
@Component
public class KafkaMessageTransformer {
    @Transactable
    @Loggable
    @Handler
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        processing Logic...
    }
}
```

Route Usage:

```
from(RouteDispatchKafkaMessage.getEndpoint()).id(RouteDispatchKafkaMessage.getEndpoint()).routeId(RouteDispatchKafkaMessage.getEndpoint())
    .bean(StepKafkaMessageTransformer.getEndpoint())

from(RouteKafkaMessageTransformer.getEndpoint())
    .routeId(RouteKafkaMessageTransformer.getEndpoint())
    .bean(StepKafkaMessageTransformer.getEndpoint())
    .id(StepKafkaMessageTransformer.getEndpoint())
;
```

ERROR CONSOLE:

```
org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route12 at: >>> To[kafkaMessageTransformer] <<< in route: Route(route12)[From[direct:xxxDispatcher] -> [OnExce... because of No endpoint could be found for: kafkaMessageTransformer, please check your classpath contains the needed Camel component jar.
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.RouteReifier.doCreateRoute(RouteReifier.java:393)
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.RouteReifier.createRoute(RouteReifier.java:117)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:368)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:342)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doInit(AbstractCamelContext.java:2612)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.init(BaseService.java:83)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.init(AbstractCamelContext.java:2435)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:111)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.start(AbstractCamelContext.java:2452)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.start(SpringCamelContext.java:121)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean.start(CamelContextFactoryBean.java:381)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean.onApplicationEvent(CamelContextFactoryBean.java:428)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean.onApplicationEvent(CamelContextFactoryBean.java:96)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:151)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:128)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:331)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:773)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:483)
    at com.walmart.platform.scm.client.execution.ScmServletContextListener.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ScmServletContextListener.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5128)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5653)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1007)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:983)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:639)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1898)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:302)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:577)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:302)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:468)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1408)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.camel.NoSuchEndpointException: No endpoint could be found for: kafkaMessageTransformer, please check your classpath contains the needed Camel component jar.
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doGetEndpoint(AbstractCamelContext.java:831)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.getEndpoint(AbstractCamelContext.java:768)
    at org.apache.camel.support.CamelContextHelper.resolveEndpoint(CamelContextHelper.java:123)
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.SendReifier.resolveEndpoint(SendReifier.java:43)
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.SendReifier.createProcessor(SendReifier.java:36)
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.ProcessorReifier.makeProcessor(ProcessorReifier.java:766)
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.ProcessorReifier.addRoutes(ProcessorReifier.java:511)
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.RouteReifier.doCreateRoute(RouteReifier.java:391)
    ... 67 more
```

1. tried to import camel-direct in pom file.
2. tried to add bean name in the component.